# Media Error with Google App Engine Deployment

Tags: windows, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have successfully deployed a running website on the app engine - here is the URL:

https://black-backup-96302.appspot.com/

This website was on a PHP hosting, and we migrated it to Google Apps, and deployed it using the App Engine. I understand that to put up any media, I will have to change my local version, and then re-deploy it. Same goes for plugins. However, when I browse into my local version using the App Engine launcher, login wordpress, and try to add an image in the media section, I get an error, as shown in the image below:

[image: Media error]

I googled this, and understand it is a permission error from the file system. My folder has a "Read only" checkbox which is marked blue, and no matter how many times I uncheck it, it is checked again.

[image]

I also assigned all the users full control, i.e. the following privileges (to folders, and subfolders)

[image]

Any help or ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = 1` to your php.ini file should fix the issue.

Comment: Although learning to know that such a parameter existed, this did not work for me :-(